# How to enable tab key in scratch buffer of emacs?

Tags: emacs

Why tab does not work in scratch buffer of emacs? Is there any setting which will enable the tab in scratch buffer?

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://www.pement.org/emacs_tabs.htm#nothing) helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TAB key not working in scratch buffer of emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57566995/tab-key-not-working-in-scratch-buffer-of-emacs)